# How to validate radio button values in redux forms ?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am designing an application which contains check boxes and radio buttons.

There are three radio buttons which are placed in three different components. As showed below, I wanted to validate any of these radio buttons (or options) checked or not. How to achieve this ? (I am using redux-form 6.4.3)

**Radio1.js**

```
Import { Field } from 'redux-form';
   class radio1 extends react.component {

     render () {

       return (  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                       <td>
                          <Field component={renderInput} type="radio" value="radio1" /></td> 
                        <td>This is radio button 1</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
             </td>
           <tr>
        )
      }
    }
export default radio1;
```

**Radio2.js**

```
 Import { Field } from 'redux-form';
class radio2 extends react.component {

 render () {

   return (  
        <tr>
            <td>
               <table>
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                             <Field component={renderInput} type="radio" value="radio2" /></td> 
                              <td>This is radio button 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
                </td>
               </tr>
    )
  }
}
export default radio2;
```

**Radio3.js**

```
 Import { Field } from 'redux-form';
class radio3 extends react.component {

 render () {

   return (  
        <tr>
          <td>
             <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                       <Field component={renderInput} type="radio" value="radio3" /></td> 
                          <td>This is radio button 3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
             </td>
          </tr>
    )
  }
}
export default radio3;
```

**renderInput.js**

```
       const renderInput= ({input, placeholder, defaultValue, meta: {touched, error, warning}}) =>        
        <div>
          <input {...input} type={type} />
        </div>
);

export default renderInput;
```

**Main.js**

```
import radio1 from './radio1';
import radio2 from './radio2';
import radio3 from './radio3';

class Main extends React.Component {

render () {
return (
<table>
<tbody>
<radio1  />
<radio2  />
<radio3  />
</tbody>
</table>

)

}

}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass the same name parameter to all the Fields
   `<Field name="myRadio" ... />`
2. Create a validation function

```
const validate = values => {
    let errors = {};

    if (!values.myRadio){
        errors.myRadio = 'Required';
    }

    return errors;
};
```

3. Add this function to `reduxForm()`

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'syncValidation',  // a unique identifier for this form
  validate                 // <--- validation function given to redux-form
})(SyncValidationForm)
```

More here: https://redux-form.com/6.8.0/examples/syncvalidation/

Comment: This is good but it shows one error message per Field with the same name, how to fix that ?

Answer (score -3):

`Field` component has a `validate` prop. You can pass a function that will validate your value

```
function validateRadio(value) {
   if(!value) {
     return 'You need to check this value'
   }
}
<Field component={renderInput} type="radio" value="radio3" validate={validateRadio} />
```

Related section in the docs: http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/Field.md/